# Remove hardcoded CSS from /review/.../stats

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, design

The user tile belonging to the logged in user (yourself) has CSS baked into the HTML.

[image]

Would be nice if a CSS class could be utilized to achieve this.

Comment: Looks like its built in for the badge progress indicator as well http://i.stack.imgur.com/BVgXi.png

Comment: Do you have any other justification for the devs spending time on this beyond it "would be nice"?  What is the reason you feel the inline CSS should be removed? (just playing devil's advocate here)

Comment: @jadarnel27: No, I don't have any proper reason beyond that. I actually somewhat assumed it's an oversight. Personally, it's holding me back from completing http://stackapps.com/questions/3724/super-user-dark-theme

Comment: I think that improving user experience by allowing more granular control over user-styles is a pretty good justification, actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be classified on the next build.